# word 365 - how to change text format/shading /striketrough in one column based on selection of value in dropdown in table column next to it?

Tags: vba, ms-word, conditional-formatting

I am trying to create a table with text values in column one and drop down lists in column 2 and text in column 1 on same row where drop down selection is made has to change to RED bolted / Black Italic or be double strike through with light grey shade depending on the selected drop down value.

Column 1

Column 2 (each cell below contains a dropdown list control with the options "Mandatory"/"Optional"/"NotApplicable")

Text on same row in column 1 to be bold and red if option selected in column 2 = Mandatory

Select

Text to be italicized if option selected = Optional

Select

Text to be double strikethrough/light grey shade if option selected = N/A

Select

I have never worked with VBA but forum replies in the Word 365 community referred to VBA to achieve this.

I tried copy pasting a table from Excel but conditional formatting did not copy over. I have not found easy clear options in word 365 to achieve similar conditional formatting tools.

Hoping someone is able to help me.

Answer (score 0):

*This is much easier to do in Excel than in Word.*

### You could try inserting an Excel table directly into Word as an Excel part.

**That should carry over the conditional formatting.**

Insert > Object > Microsoft Excel Worksheet

[image: screenshot of dialog]

That gives you all of the tools from Excel in that part of your document.

You can, instead, link to an existing file.

[image: screenshot]

In Word, conditional formatting is accomplished by [IF fields](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#IF_field) that have the (duplicated) content formatted two ways or by using vba (macros). Neither of these is particularly simple to implement.

Here are links showing how to add an Excel part to a Word document. You want to be inserting as an **Embedded object**, not just the data.

- [How to Insert an Excel Worksheet into a Word document](https://helpdeskgeek.com/office-tips/embed-an-excel-worksheet-into-word/)
- [How to Insert Excel data into a Word document](https://spreadsheeto.com/excel-to-word/).

Once you have the part in your document, it will look just like ordinary text but can carry formatting created by Excel. To edit it, right-click and pick Object from the context menu.